# How to infer about the volume of the body from measuring the mass of the object in 2 different liquids?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, fluid-statics, density, buoyancy

While solving a problem on hydro statics subject I saw a statement that argued that if I know the weight of the object in the air and then I know the weight of the object in the water.so when I subtract between the weight I can conclude the volume of the objects.

I have numeric example:

weight in air is $740 gm$

weight in water is $690 gm$

so the difference is $$m = 740- 690= 50 gm$$ and somehow they concluded that the volume is $50 cm^3$

what is the explanation for that? is it about the Archimedes law?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be  two possible cases

**Case 1**

The statement in your book might be wrong (Though more likely possibility is that statement in the book might be correct but what you read /inferred from it is wrong).In that case you are right. We can only subtract two quantities with same dimensions. In your case it is mass.
We can't get a different quantity when we subtract two same  quantity with same dimensions .

**Case 2**

What i think it is-
They meant volume of object submerged in the water is $50cm^3$. It is only because as density of water is 1 $gm \ cm^{-3}$. Now in case of water 50gm = 50  $cm^3$ but it still not actual volume of the object. It is the volume of object submerged in the liquid.If the object is fully submerged then the book is correct.

Infact, this the actual statement of Archimedes Principle - The volume of liquid displaced is equal to the the volume of object submerged in the liquid.

Comment: Thank you, so I just want to be sure that I understood you,
you say that I know the mass of the object submerged is $50 gm$ and I know the density of the water so I just use the relation $\rho=\frac{m}{v}$ and this is will tell me the volume of the object that submerged in the water?

Comment: No! 50gm is the mass of water displaced. Volume of water displaced =volume of object submerged  which  is equal to be 50cm^3 . To calculate object's mass u should know it's density.